# Beamer: citing distinct works outputs the same reference label

Tags: beamer, bibtex, citing, natbib

I'm working on a beamer presentation and I want to use Natbib for references. However, regardless of what bib key I put into the \cite command, the same reference label gets printed in the output file.

Here's my preamble with a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} 
\usefonttheme{serif} 
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[osfI]{garamondx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}



\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{dresden}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Overview}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \cite{Arntzenius2003-ARNOWW}

    \cite{Boolos1971-BOOTIC}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \bibliography{C:/Users/Public/References/dump.bib} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `natbib` does not allow you to make that differentiation, mainly because BibTeX doesnt; it just truncates the author list. For the differentiation you want you'd need to use BibLaTeX and Biber.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik wouldn't it be likely that the `Boolos1971-BOOTIC` reference has different authors (and a different year), and should therefore be shown? @Antonio, can you show the contents of these two items in the `.bib` file?

Comment: @Marijn Hm... Judging by the citation key, you are probably correct...

Comment: @Marijn that's correct and my problem is exactly that even though the keys have different contents the same output gets printed. The content of `Arntzenius2003-ARNOWW` is `@Article{Arntzenius2003-ARNOWW,
  author    = {Frank Arntzenius and Ned Hall},
  title     = {{On What We Know About Chance}},
  journal   = {British Journal for the Philosophy of Science},
  year      = {2003},
  volume    = {54},
  number    = {2},
  pages     = {171--179},
  groups    = {Deference,Chance },
  publisher = {Br Soc Philosophy Sci},
}`

Comment: @Marijn and the content of `Boolos1971-BOOTIC` is `@Article{Boolos1971-BOOTIC,
  author    = {George Boolos},
  title     = {{The Iterative Conception of Set}},
  journal   = {Journal of Philosophy},
  year      = {1971},
  volume    = {68},
  number    = {8},
  pages     = {215--231},
  doi       = {10.2307/2025204},
  file      = {:Boolos1971-BOOTIC - The Iterative Conception of Set.pdf:PDF},
  groups    = {Philosophy of Logic and Mathematics, Philosophy of Set Theory},
  publisher = {Journal of Philosophy Inc},
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by a combination of overlays and cite keys. Because the default overlay specification is `<+->` the bibliography is shown incrementally. This means that the first bibliography item is shown on two slides, and the id is therefore duplicated. This confuses `hyperref` and the output becomes incorrect - it shouldn't be, this is a bug.

As a workaround you can switch off the overlay specification for the bibliography slide, i.e., reset it to the default value of `<*>` (show everything on a slide simultaneously). For a list of references that may be a preferable way of presenting in general.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{natbib}

\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \cite{Arntzenius2003-ARNOWW}

    \cite{Boolos1971-BOOTIC}
\end{frame}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<*>}
\begin{frame}
    \bibliography{phil.bib} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]